# Setting libxml_disable_entity_loader(false) in Magento - security concerns

Tags: php, security, magento, libxml2

I have a Magento shop on a server with php configured as **fcgi**. Lately I've been having problems with **libxml_disable_entity_loader**.

Apparently, setting it to true will make **simplexml_load_file** always return false according to [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62577) bug report. 
Because of my server configuration this setting will persists and this makes the
shop unaccessible.

Since this setting is for security, how bad would it be if I set it to false before each request? In index.php for example.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is being solved the same way in the latest version of Magento. There is a new file in *app* called **bootstrap.php** that is included in **index.php** with the following contents:

```
/**
* Apply workaround for the libxml PHP bugs:
* @link https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62577
* @link https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64938
*/
if (function_exists('libxml_disable_entity_loader')) {
    libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
}
```

I didn't check in which version if appears first, but it is there in enterprise version 1.14.2.4